# How do I register custom Logback Filters using OSGi fragment bundle?

Tags: java, osgi, logback, osgi-fragment

I have a custom Filter called `foo.bar.MatcherFilter`.

I have it declared in logback.xml,

```
<appender ....>
  <filter class="foo.bar.MatcherFilter">
    <contains>java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused</contains>
  </filter>
</appender>
```

At first, when `MatcherFilter` is bundled within my application bundle, Logback would report `ClassNotFoundException`.

So I bundled `foo.bar.MatcherFilter` as a Fragment Bundle,

```
Export-Package: foo.bar.*
Fragment-Host: ch.qos.logback.core
```

Still I'm getting the same `ClassNotFoundException`.

I understand that fragments would share the classloader from the host bundle. Thus, Logback should be able to instantiate `MatcherFilter`. Correct me if I'm mistaken.

Registering custom Filter using OSGi fragment bundle, can this be done?

Answer (score 2):

As the Logger is initialized by the `LoggerContext` and Logback uses the [classloader of the `Context` class](https://github.com/qos-ch/logback/blob/master/logback-core/src/main/java/ch/qos/logback/core/util/OptionHelper.java#L31) you would probably need to make the `Fragment-Host` as `ch.qos.logback.classic` which contains the `LoggerContext` class